# Photoelectric Effect Graph: Interpretation of Intensity vs

Tags: photoelectric-effect, si-units, intensity

[image]

After performing dimensional analysis of the current versus voltage graph when studying the photoelectric effect, this graph should measure units of siemens. It shows, however, high intensity and low intensity when looking at different positions of this graph. Can anyone clarify what the information the Current vs Applied Voltage graph actually provides: intensity or siemens?

Comment: It shows two curves: one I-V curve measured when light intensity is high, one when light intensity is low. I do not understand where conductivity would come in.

Comment: @Pieter Your comment clarified how to interpret the graph. Thank you~